# standard sql: casting strings in array as float64

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-datalab

I am trying to cast the fields GCAM_value and Themes_value as number such as float64.

I have tried CAST(regexp_extract(x, r'^(.*?):') as FLOAT64) but got an error message as the code stumbles over NULL values.

```
#standardSQL

SELECT
  GKGRECORDID,
  DATE, 
  ARRAY(
    SELECT regexp_extract(x, r'^(.*?)\:')
    FROM UNNEST(split(GCAM,',')) AS x
    WHERE regexp_extract(x, r'^(.*?)\:') IS NOT NULL
  ) AS GCAM_field,
   ARRAY(
    SELECT regexp_extract(x, r'[^:]*$')
    FROM UNNEST(split(GCAM,',')) AS x
    WHERE regexp_extract(x, r'[^:]*$') IS NOT NULL
  ) AS GCAM_value,

    ARRAY(
    SELECT regexp_extract(x, r'^(.*?)\,')
    FROM UNNEST(split(V2Themes,';')) AS x
    WHERE regexp_extract(x, r'^(.*?)\,') IS NOT NULL
  ) AS Theme_field,
   ARRAY(
    SELECT regexp_extract(x, r'[^,]*$')
    FROM UNNEST(split(V2Themes,';')) AS x
    WHERE regexp_extract(x, r'[^,]*$') IS NOT NULL
  ) AS Theme_value,

  TranslationInfo,
  V2Tone,
  SourceCollectionIdentifier,
  SourceCommonName,
  DocumentIdentifier
FROM `gdelt-bq.gdeltv2.gkg_partitioned`
WHERE _PARTITIONTIME BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('2019-02-02') AND TIMESTAMP('2019- 
02-02')
```

I would like the array items for GCAM_value and Themes_value to be in some numeric format like float64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below should be good starting point for you

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  GKGRECORDID,
  DATE, 
  ARRAY(
    SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(x, r'^(.*?)\:')
    FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(GCAM,',')) AS x
    WHERE REGEXP_EXTRACT(x, r'^(.*?)\:') IS NOT NULL
  ) AS GCAM_field,
  ARRAY(
    SELECT CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(x, r'[^:]*$') AS FLOAT64)
    FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(GCAM,',')) AS x
    WHERE IFNULL(REGEXP_EXTRACT(x, r'[^:]*$'), '') != ''
  ) AS GCAM_value,
  ARRAY(
    SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(x, r'^(.*?)\,')
    FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(V2Themes,';')) AS x
    WHERE REGEXP_EXTRACT(x, r'^(.*?)\,') IS NOT NULL
  ) AS Theme_field,
  ARRAY(
    SELECT CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(x, r'[^,]*$') AS FLOAT64)
    FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(V2Themes,';')) AS x
    WHERE IFNULL(REGEXP_EXTRACT(x, r'[^,]*$'), '') != ''
  ) AS Theme_value,
  TranslationInfo,
  V2Tone,
  SourceCollectionIdentifier,
  SourceCommonName,
  DocumentIdentifier
FROM `gdelt-bq.gdeltv2.gkg_partitioned`
WHERE _PARTITIONTIME BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('2019-02-02') AND TIMESTAMP('2019-02-02')
```

It returns `REPEATED FLOAT` instead `REPEATED STRING` for respective fields